# Localization request permission base on the application language not device language

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, localization

`Localization` is working fine in my application. I want localization the permission dialog text messages. It is working fine with the device language changes but I want to change message according to my application language.

I have tried the following code

```
import UIKit

class LocalizeHelper: NSObject {

    private var myBundle: Bundle? = nil

    static let shared: LocalizeHelper = {
        let instance = LocalizeHelper()
        return instance
    }()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        // use systems main bundle as default bundle
        myBundle = Bundle.main

    }

    func localizedString(forKey key: String) -> String {
        return myBundle!.localizedString(forKey: key, value: "", table: nil)
    }

    //  Converted with Swiftify v1.0.6331 - https://objectivec2swift.com/
    func setLanguage(_ lang: String) {
        // path to this languages bundle
        let path: String? = Bundle.main.path(forResource: lang, ofType: "lproj")
        if path == nil {
            // there is no bundle for that language
            // use main bundle instead
            myBundle = Bundle.main
        }
        else {
            // use this bundle as my bundle from now on:
            myBundle = Bundle(path: path!)
            // to be absolutely shure (this is probably unnecessary):
            if myBundle == nil {
                myBundle = Bundle.main
            }
        }
    }

    func getLanguage() -> String {
        print("\(String(describing: myBundle?.bundlePath.last))")
        //return myBundle!.bundlePath.last >> Error
        return myBundle!.bundlePath.lastCharacter!
    }
}

extension String {
    public var lastCharacter: String? {
        guard let aLast = self.last else {
            return nil
        }
        return String(aLast)
    }
}
```

[image]

I have surfed in StackOverflow but didn't find any solution. Any help shell we appreciated.

Comment: Localization support based on the device language, I was also in the same situation content should change based on application language, so what I did is whatever language I select from the app that I stored in `user defaults` based on the condition changed the text. go through this link https://github.com/Decybel07/L10n-swift

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to save the application's language in the user defaults as a string for example and then when you take it out of user defaults parse it as a custom app language enum. If you don't have any app language save you can always fall through to the device language but prefer or override it with the app language in user defaults not being nil. Also preferably you should wrap your user defaults interactions with a user defaults manager that you access in your view controller.

So the suggested steps are:

- create userdefualts manager
- define language enum
- implement setLanguage func language parameter
- implement getLanguage func language output with device language or
  english as guard return